# Website address hacked, emails created but not showing in manage your account

Tags: security, email, spam

I have a website, `thebleudoor.com`. It is hosted by yahoo. It gets 2000-3000 hits a day and has been for at least 5 years.

A few months ago, as admin of the website, I started getting bounced back emails from newly created emails like `d4f7a91f9@thebleudoor.com`. Yahoo only shows 2 emails for my account. They said they can't do anything about it.

Now, my "*spam hacked email accounts*" are getting spam. They haven't altered or used my website or email or bank info, just the good name of my website. Is there anything I can do? Do I need to be concerned?

Changing my provider won't really help will it?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand from your question,  website is not hacked. probably it is a [joe job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_job), they're just sending emails that looks like it's from your domain.

Comment: Thank you. Joe job as a name for it helped me find spam cop which had concrete steps for action.